# Что лучше использовать для хранения String переменных на постоянной основе?

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences, хранение-данных, fileoutputstream

SharedPreference, или FileOutputStream, или есть иные варианты?

Задача: нужно создать 4 файла для хранения String переменных, далее при определенных условиях добавляем в один из четырех файлов String переменную. А потом просто сравниваем новую String переменную с переменными из одного из четырех файлов.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222499/share-preferences-or-internal-file-storage-any-memory-issue

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko спасибо, если вы разместите ваш комментарий в ответах, я смогу его отметить как "правильный"

Comment: Базу данных с одной таблицей в четыре столбца.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja разве это того стоит, чтобы использовать SQLite? Ведь нам нужно лишь добавление и сравнение.

Comment: Из вашей задачи непонятно ничего о объемах и количестве данных. В Андроид SQLite идет "из коробки" и часто проще работать с ней, чем с файлами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. SharedPreference: хранить личные примитивные данные в парах ключ-значение. (Для хранения небольших записей / данных).
2. Внутреннее хранилище: хранить личные данные в памяти устройства. (Для хранения больших наборов данных).

Здесь [ссылка](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage) на документацию про хранение данных. 
Вот [первоисточник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222499/share-preferences-or-internal-file-storage-any-memory-issue) ответа, там есть много ответов по вашей проблеме. Удачи :)